# jqGrid pagination page number text box not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

It's kinda weird but whatever I do the page number field in the pager is not updating. I can enter page number and it will return proper records, it returns proper page number info on calling

`$('#jqGrid01').getGridParam('page')`

If I use pager buttons it will refresh the grid properly but NOT update the page number in the text field!

[image]

Here is the grid code..

```
jQuery("#jqGrid01").jqGrid({
// data: mydata, datatype: "local",
url:'localhost/gridx/dashb_grid', mtype : "get", datatype: "json",
jsonReader: { root: "rows", page: "page", total: "total", records: "records", repeatitems: true, cell: 'cell', id: 'stock1', userdata: 'userdata'},
height: $gridh, rowNum: 100, rowList: [100,200,300,500,1000,2000,3000],
colNames:['Stock 1','Stock 2', 'Price 1', 'Price 2','Ratio','Correlation','ST % Mean', 'ST Drift', 'LT % Mean', 'LT Drift', 'RSI', 'RSI Drift', 'Beta 1', 'Beta 2',     'Industry 1', 'Industry 2', 'Earnings 1', 'Earnings 2'],
colModel:[
    {name:'stock1',index:'stock1', width:30, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','cn','bw','ew','lt','gt']}},
    {name:'stock2',index:'stock2', width:30, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','cn','bw','ew','lt','gt']}},
    {name:'price1',index:'price1', width:30, sorttype:"float", align:"right", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}},
    {name:'price2',index:'price2', width:30, sorttype:"float", align:"right", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}},
    {name:'ratio',index:'ratio', width:30, sorttype:"float", align:"right", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}},
    {name:'correlation',index:'correlation', width:42, sorttype:"float", align:"right", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}},
    {name:'st_mean',index:'st_mean', width:38, sorttype:"float", align:"right", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}},
    {name:'st_drift',index:'st_drift', width:35, sorttype:"float", align:"right", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}},
    {name:'lt_mean',index:'lt_mean', width:39, sorttype:"float", align:"right", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}},
    {name:'lt_drift',index:'lt_drift', width:35, sorttype:"float", align:"right", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}},
    {name:'rsi',index:'rsi', width:30, sorttype:"int", align:"right", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}},
    {name:'rsi_drift',index:'rsi_drift', width:35, sorttype:"float", align:"right", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}},
    {name:'beta1',index:'beta1', width:30, sorttype:"float", align:"right", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}},
    {name:'beta2',index:'beta2', width:30, sorttype:"float", align:"right", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}},
    {name:'industry1',index:'industry1', width:102, search:false},
    {name:'industry2',index:'industry2', width:102, search:false},
    {name:'earnings1',index:'earnings1', width:45, sorttype:"float", align:"right", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}},
    {name:'earnings2',index:'earnings2', width:45, sorttype:"float", align:"right", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}}
],
pager: "#jqGridPager01",
viewrecords: true, hidegrid:false,
sortname: 'stock1', sortorder: 'asc',
loadComplete: function() {
    // test

}
});
```

Also tried inspecting the textbox element but it has no id so I can't manually set it and I couldn't find anything in jqGrid docs or google to set it!!

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, how to fix it!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include `loadonce:true` for your pagination to work.

It indicates to do the **client side pagination** rather than **server side pagination**

Also it indicates that you are `loading all the records at the same time`

If you **do not want to load all the records** at a time , then is a completely different scenario where you need to take care of **paging parameters** in the url for fetching data in the server side.

When you are using **server side paging**, jqgrid automatically posts parameters called `page` and `rows`.

Here, Page indicates the **current page** you are in and rows indicates number of records per page.

So, you need send these **params to database** and fetch accordingly to get data page wise.

Since, you mentioned **datatype as JSon** which **means server side processing**. it `assumes` that you are interested in `Server side paging`.

it expects you return **page and rows** in JSOn response. Since you json does not contain any of these, it is by default showing as zero.

So, the `pagination obviuosly will not work`.

**If you are using dotnet for server side: here is the small example:**

```
   [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult LoadPackages(int page, int rows, string sord, string sidx, string PackageNumber)
        {

            liPackages = new List<PackageModel>();
            if (PackageNumber == "")
            {
                liPackages = _packageRepository.LoadPackages((page - 1) * rows, rows, sord, sidx, out strTotalRecords);
                long lCount = Convert.ToInt64(strTotalRecords);
                return Json(new
                {
                    total = Math.Ceiling((Decimal)lCount / (Decimal)rows),
                    page = page,
                    records = lCount,
                    rows = liPackages
                },
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
          }
```

**Updated2:**

Can you try including `gridview:true`

**Updated3**

Change method type from GET to POST like this : `mType:POST`

Comment: These grids I'm working on will return no less then 10k records so I don't think using loadonce would be a good idea! Pagination must happen in server side in my case unfortunately!

Comment: Updated..with server side pagination. And yes you obviously had to go with server side pagination.

Comment: @Anupam..are you using java or dotnet?

Comment: I'm using PHP/MSSQL! Also pagination is not my problem really. Grid is working fine with proper results in every way (searching/sorting/pagination). It's just that page number is not updating somehow! If I put a page number in that box and hit enter I get exactly what I want, if I use pagination buttons it works but does not fill the page number as it should!

Comment: @Anupam..you can see along with my grid records , i am sending totalnumberof pages ,current page number, current records. If you are missing any of these fields in the JSON Response, then Jqgrid Paging functionality will not work. This is just because , Jqgrid uses these particular fields that i have been mentioning  are the onces that Jqgrid uses for pagination. Since, they are not present in your JSON response. you are getting zero instead of appropriate page number. hope this makes understand what you are misssing

Comment: I'm using almost the same code you posted! I can see the JSON code with proper details!

Comment: Yes..I can see the image. you are getting the records and total count. I am not sure which is causing the problem. Can you try including gridview:true as you can see in my updated answer.

Comment: @Anupam..Can you just check what is the json response you are getting the browser console.see whether you are getting the correct page number from the server each time a request is being made

Comment: {"total":5,"page":1,"records":435,"rows":[{"stock1":"AXP","stock2":"BA","price1":89,"price2":123,"ratio":0.72,"correlation":0,"st_mean":0,"st_drift":0,"lt_mean":0,"lt_drift":0,"rsi":0,"rsi_drift":0,"beta1":0,"beta2":0,"industry1":"Credit Services","industry2":"Aerospace\/Defense Products & Services","earnings1":4.88,"earnings2":5.96},...]} is top of the JSON dump being created. Please let me know if you see anything wrong. Thanks for the suggestions, really appreciate it. I'll find out if [gridview:true] works..

Comment: @Anupam..Your JSON Response seems absoulutely fine.. I see nothing wrong in it.

Comment: @Anumpam..If you are using latest version of Jqgrid. There is no need to use JSON Reader. jqgrid will automatically take care of it.

Comment: @Anupam..Change the mType:POST rather than GET